# What unique Blades are not available through random drop from generic Cores Crystals?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Most of my unique blades were obtained randomly by activating common and rare core crystals. Yet, some of those Blades were obtained by putting some effort into certain activities. E.g.

> Kasandra's core crystal from rumor, Vess and Praxis crystals from side quests

So, how much Blades are obtainable through some activity in game, not activating Common/Rare/Legendary Core Crystals? Obviously I'm not counting Core Crystals you get by plot, e.g.

> Wulfric or Rok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I'm going to include the ones you mentioned. There are 8 in total.

> Roc - Roc's Core Crystal - gained via story

- Wulfric - Beastly Core Crystal - gained via story
- Kasandra - Lucky Core Crystal - gained via salvaging at the salvage point in Chansagh Wastes until a Gluttonous Marrin spawns, which would drop this crystal
- Herald - Sealed Core Crystal - gained via feeding "blood-related" items to the Shrine of Sealing in Theosoir, Tantal
- Sheba - Inherited Core Crystal - gained via spending 500k at the shop in Gormott
- Vess - Vess's Core Crystal - gained by doing Vess' sidequest ("Tranquility") in Gormott
- Praxis - Praxis's Core Crystal - gained by doing the Crystal Clear side quest
- Theory - Theory's Core Crystal - gained by doing the Blade-Sharp Memory side quest (this is related to Praxis)

In fact, one thing worth mentioning is that all of these Blades are available through a common core crystal drop if you release them. This is a strategy that was used to trade Blades before Overdrive Protocol farming was possible.

Comment: This list is missing Poppibuster, which was added via a side quest that is included in the DLC. Additionally, it's worth noting that Poppibuster can be engaged by anyone except Tora at any time and still has access to its full affinity capability while in the Spirit Crucible Elpys.